# How to automatically detect NavigationBarTitle displayMode become .inline or .large in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a `List` inside a `navigationView` and I want to change the `List` `Section` text whenever the list is scrolled and the `navigationBarTitle` become `.inline` or `.large`

This is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@State private var scrolledUp = false

var body: some View {

    NavigationView {

        if scrolledUp {

            List {
                Section(header: Text("Moved UP"))
                {
                    Text("Line1").bold()
                    Text("Line2").bold()
                    Text("Line2").bold()

                }

                .navigationBarTitle("Setting")
            }

        } else {

            List {
                Section(header: Text("Not Moved"))
                {
                    Text("Line1").bold()
                    Text("Line2").bold()
                    Text("Line2").bold()

                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Setting")
        }  
     }
   }
}
```

how can I find out the `list` is scrolled and the `navigationBar` is changed to `.title`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I used `geometryReader` to detect the y position of the `List` `section` `header`. During the scroll. If the position is less than 80, the `navigationBarTitle` is changed to `.title`.

It works perfectly. However, I still looking for a better solution.

Comment: I am also interested in this. May you can share your solution by providing sample code? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a rough implementation used to turn on additional nav bar items when it turns from `.large` to `.inline`. It is not perfect, but it is enough for some situations.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var navIsInline = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                ZStack {
                    LazyVStack {
                        ForEach(1..<100) { val in
                            Text("Hello, NavBar! \(val)")
                        }
                    }
                    GeometryReader { proxy in
                        let offset = proxy.frame(in: .named("scroll")).minY
                        Color.clear.preference(key: ViewOffsetKey.self, value: offset)
                    }
                }
            }
            .coordinateSpace(name: "scroll")
            .onPreferenceChange(ViewOffsetKey.self) { value in
                print(value)
                if navIsInline != (value < 0) {
                    navIsInline.toggle()
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
            .navigationTitle("Nav title")
            .toolbar {
                if navIsInline {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        Text("leading")
                    }
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigation) {
                        Text("Navigation")
                            .font(.headline)
                    }
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Trailing").font(.headline)
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                    }
                }
            }
            //.toolbar(navIsInline ? .hidden : .visible, for: .navigationBar)
        }
    }
}

struct ViewOffsetKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = CGFloat
    static var defaultValue = CGFloat.zero
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value += nextValue()
    }
}
```